# get( ) takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Tags: python, tkinter, get

```
def get_input():
        global inputValue
        inputValue=movie_url.get("1.0","end-1c")
        inp = re.match(r'^((http|https)\:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\?\:@\-_=#]+\.([a-zA-Z]){2,6}([a-zA-Z0-9\.\&\/\?\:@\-_=#])*imdb.com', inputValue)
        if inp == False:
            box3 = messagebox.showerror("Error","Unknown Error!!")  



m = tk.Tk() #master shortened to m
m.title('PosterMan')
m.geometry('300x200')

label = ttk.Label(m, text = "Enter URL")

movie_url=tk.StringVar()
url_entered =ttk.Entry(m,width =15,textvariable= movie_url)
url_entered.pack(ipadx=0,ipady=1)



b1 = ttk.Button(m, text="Click",command=get_input)
b1.pack(pady=(20,0), ipadx=50, ipady=5)
b1 = ttk.Button(m, text="Convert to .ico")#, command=cover)
b1.pack(pady=(20,0), ipadx=50, ipady=5)
b1 = ttk.Button(m, text="Set Icon")#, command=open_browser)
b1.pack(pady=(20,0), ipadx=30, ipady=5)

m.mainloop()
```

** I'm trying to take a URL as input and check whether it is an IMDB url. 'get() takes one positional argument but three were given' is the error shown**

This code is aimed to extract movie poster from IMDB

Comment: What does `movie_url.get("1.0","end-1c")` supposed to do? You should do `movie_url.get()` to get the value from the input field.

Comment: I think the error is self explanatory. Instead of `get("1.0","end-1c")` try `get()`. You are clearly told this method accept only 1 argument, which is `self`

Comment: Please show the actual error in the body of the question.